# Cyrillic text in ngerman document

Tags: fonts, unicode, input-encodings, font-encodings, cyrillic

I have a long German text that contains cryillic. Up until this point I had this and it worked fine, allowing me to write umlauts etc:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}

\begin{document}
Алина
\end{document}
```

But with Cyrillic this gives the following error:

```
! Package inputenc Error: Unicode char А (U+410)
(inputenc)                not set up for use with LaTeX.
```

No combination of `inputenc` and `fontenc` options seems to change this.

Edit: I should note that with `usepackage[russian]{babel}` it works fine, it's just the mixing that's the issue

Answer (score 1):

Mark up your document. Note also that T1 is essentially mandatory for German, but it should be loaded last if the main document language is German.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T2A,T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[russian,ngerman]{babel}

\begin{document}

Flügel \foreignlanguage{russian}{крылья}

\end{document}
```

> Flügel крылья

<sub>No image at the moment for problems with imgur</sub>

Comment: I have the same problem and tried to run your solution by itself: it still produces the same problem. It has worked before for me but that was on another Linux distro... Now it keeps saying: "Font T2A/cmr/m/n/10=larm1000 at 10.0pt not loadable: Metric (TFM) file not found" -- how do I fix this on OpenSuse? Thank you so much in advance!

Answer (score 1):

I would advise using `polyglossia` package, which automatically calls `fontspec`, thus requres **XeLaTeX** or **LuaLaTeX** to compile.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{polyglossia}

\setmainfont{Times New Roman}
\setmainlanguage{german}

\begin{document}
Алина
\end{document}
```

**EDIT:** The reason I have set `Times` as default is that `polyglossia` loads the `Latin Modern` as default, which has no support for Cyrillic.

Answer (score 0):

When using Cyrillic language make sure to specify the appropriate font encoding. I only tried `T1`, since that's all I ever saw, but Cyrillic requires `T2A`.

I added the following before your inputenc statement:

```
\usepackage[T1,T2A]{fontenc}
```

to use both `T1` and `T2A` languages.